# Converting web application to RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, jsp, servlets, frontend

I'm building a simple web application with java. Right now it contains a jsp in which the user can enter some data (via textareas in a html file), that is processed in the servlet by the program logic. After that the result gets pushed back to the jsp by setattribute and is displayed to the user. Its working quite fine...

Now I'm told to convert this program to the REST architecture, which I have never heard before. I have to do this task with jax-rs and jersey. In which way does these two concepts differ from another one and do you guys have a recommendation how I should start?

Thanks for all the comments!

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick reply!

I have watched 60% of the tutorial recommended in the comments and now I'm understanding the REST architecture to some extend.

Nevertheless I'm confused how to start with my application, which should transform an input to another encoding (for example: base64 to binary).

With my understanding right now I write the origin input in the request body of a post method(?) and receive the encoded data in the respond body.
A conversion would look like this:
/conversion/{format1}/{format2}

Is this approach is somewhat correct?

Secondly do I have to create a method for each conversion (like base64 --> binary or base64 --> hex) or is there any way to avoid this?

Soz for my poor English...

Comment: I recommend that you start by writing code. And when you have a specific problem with code you have written, you should ask about that specific problem here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is too broad for this site. Please take some time to go through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to review what type of questions are good questions for this site. Thanks, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody can answer your question fully with one reply post here.
I would advise you to learn about REST architecture first and then jax-rs and jersey.

So i would refer you this tutorial where every aforementioned topics are covered in a very easily understandable and organized way,
https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs/